# How to use Scope values from md-tabs in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

In **angular material**, **md-tabs** if there are two tabs and two buttons at end. One button for saving other to cancel the form.

```html
  <div ng-controller="jobsCtrl">
     <form name="jobDefinitionForm"> 
        <md-content>
            <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
                <md-tab label="Basic Info">
                <!-- <md-content class="md-padding"> -->
                    <div ng-include src="'/public/mods/Tab1.html'"></div>
                <!-- </md-content> -->
                </md-tab>

                <md-tab label="Brief Info">
                <!-- <md-content class="md-padding"> -->
                     <div ng-include src="'/public/mods/Tab2.html'"></div>
                <!-- </md-content> -->
                </md-tab>
           </md-tabs>
      </md-content>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

I have included two files,
if Tab one included file contains:

```html
<md-input-container class="md-block">
  <label>Title</label>
  <input ng-model="jobDes.title">
</md-input-container>
```

And if Tab two, included file contains:

```html
<md-input-container class="md-block">
  <label>Title2</label>
  <input ng-model="jobDes.title2">
 </md-input-container>
```

I'm not able to save these forms and `jobDes.title, jobDes.title2` outside included files and Md-tabs are becoming **undefined**....

```
  $scope.save= function() {
    console.log($scope.jobDes);//this is undefined
}
```

How am I supposed to get `$scope.jobDes` proper values ...

Comment: are you adding ngMaterial dependencies to your angular module ?..

Comment: yes ngMaterial dependencies has been added thats not a problem...

Comment: Omg replying so soon, ok will try to solve it tomorrow

Comment: tomorrow!?? haha..